# Equivalent statements to simply connectedness

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Show that the following are equivalent for a path connected space $X$.

(a) $X$ is simply connected. (with the definition that the fundamental group is trivial)

(b) If two paths $\alpha$ and $\beta: I\to X$ are such that $\alpha(0)=\beta(0)$ and $\alpha(1)=\beta(1)$, then $\alpha$ is path homotopic to $\beta$.

(c) Every continuous map $f: S^1 \to X$ is continuously extendible on $D^2$.

(d) Every continuous map $f: S^1 \to X$ is null-homotopic.

I've shown the directions $(a)\to (b)$ and $(c)\iff (d)$. However, I can't find the link between (a) or (b) to (c) or (d). How can I complete this proof? I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: You can't find the link between (a) and (d)?

Answer (score 0):

Consider a path $\gamma: I\to X$. Since $\gamma(1) = \gamma(0)$, you may as well consider it as a function $\tilde\gamma: S^1\simeq I/(0=1)\to X$. Then you should be good. :-)

Comment: I don't understand your argument...What does this prove?

Comment: for example, to show that (a) implies (d): according to (a) every map $\gamma: I\to X$ is nullhomotopic; then consider the $\tilde\gamma$ in my answer, and observe that also the homotopy $H$ between $\gamma$ and the constant loop can be viewed as $\tilde H: S^I\times I\to X$, for it must hold $H(0,s)=H(1,s)$. Since every continuous map $S^1\to X$ comes from a path $I\to X$, we get that any such map is nullhomotopic.